# Can't make to spring found my default controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

At the first Imma noobie in `Spring MVC` framework...
I created a project in **Intellij Idea** and it works but I can't get how to make to it found my default controller for **index.jsp**. Below a code of controller (`com.contedevel.lab01.IndexController`):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

My view (**/index.jsp**):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ConteDevel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  ${message}
  </body>
</html>
```

And **/WEB_INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.contedevel.lab01"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In browser I see a nothing instead of `${message}` but I need to see `"Hello Spring MVC Framework!"` from my controller.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you share the Url that you are using to access this page?

Comment: Yeah, of course `http://localhost:8080/Lab01_war_exploded/`

Comment: I see a correct html in my browser but without `${message}` from my controller.

Comment: Why don't you try with `ModelAndView` ?

Comment: Please try `http://localhost:8080/Lab01_war_exploded/index/index` once

Comment: Did you try with above url i mentioned?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work still... I made better: chose another project type) But thank you that u tried to help me =))